# Excel Sharing Corruption

Tags: excel, office365

I have a couple of issues:

(1) On my Excel file, the Conditional Formatting and Format as Table is grayed out. The excel is shared. If that is the cause of the problem, how can I unshare the excel to enable (ungrey out) Conditional Formatting and Format as Table?

(2) I am unable to delete the multiple sheets on my Excel file. It is being shared. If sharing is the root cause, how can I unshare my Excel File and be able to delete the sheets (the delete option is greyed out)?

(3) The Freezing Panes keep freezing the entire sheets without warning. How do I prevent that from happening?

4) The tabs sheets on the bottom of the Excel file keeps disappearing. How do I prevent that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unsharing is as easy as clicking the Share workbook button on the Review tab.
If you are on the Office insider program, there is a new feature caled co-authoring which makes the shared workbook feature obsolete. All it takes is saving the file on your OneDrive folder (or in a sharepoint folder) and open it from there. Anyone else opening that file will be able to edit. See: http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/excelcoauthoring.asp and https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Document-collaboration-and-co-authoring-ee1509b4-1f6e-401e-b04a-782d26f564a4